# Remove elements from list which are just before some specific element

Tags: python, list

Let's say I am having a list as:

```
a = ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
```

Here I want to **remove every `'no'` which is preceded by every `'yes'`**. So **my resultant list should be like**:

```
['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
```

---

I've found that in order to remove an element from a list by its value, we may use `list.remove(..)` as:

```
a = ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
a.remove('no')
print a
```

But it gives me result with only removing first occurrence of `'no'` as:

```
['no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
```

**How can I achieve the desired result by removing all the occurrence of `'no'` which are preceded by all `'yes'` in my list?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
a = ' '.join(a)  
print(a.replace('no yes', 'yes').split(' '))
```

What it is doing is:
1. merging the list into a string with `' '.join()`
2. replacing all the occurrencies of 'no yes' with 'yes' by `a.replace()`
3. splitting it back into a list with `a.split(' ')`

Comment: I see 3 problems with this: 1) It only works with strings. 2) It breaks if any of the strings contains a space. 3) It breaks if an element ends with "no" (e.g. "anno") or starts with "yes" (e.g. "yesterday"). __That said__, it's still better than that regex answer up there.

Answer (score 12):

For removing all the occurrence of `'no'` which are present just before the `'yes'` in your list, you may use *list comprehension* with [**`itertools.zip_longest(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3.x (which is equivalent of [**`iterools.izip_longest(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2.x) *(having default `fillvalue` as `None`)* to achieve this as :

```
>>> a = ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']

# Python 3.x solution
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [x for x, y in zip_longest(a, a[1:]) if not(x=='no' and y=='yes')]
['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']

# Python 2.x solution
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [x for x, y in izip_longest(a, a[1:]) if not(x=='no' and y=='yes')]
['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
```

---

You might be interested in taking a look at the [**`zip_longest`** document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which says:

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with `fillvalue`. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate with the condition and append last item:

```
[i for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]) if (i == 'yes' or j == 'no')] + a[-1:]
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I disagree. Could you provide a non-working example?

Comment: sorry, my bad, you've my +1

Answer (score 3):

An interestingly roundabout way, using `regex` with a `look-ahead`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ' '.join(a)                          # convert it into string
>>> out = re.sub('no (?=yes)', '', s)        # remove
>>> out.split()                              # get back the list
=> ['no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
```

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: This approach doesn't work if any of the elements contain a space.

Comment: @Rawing : ofcourse. Its assuming that the list only contains elements with values `yes` and `no`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

I've also attached the screenshot of the output!

```
a = ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
for i in range (1,5):
  if a[i]=='yes':
    j=i-1
    a.pop(j)

print(a)
```

**The output:**

[image]